# Export iMessages in human readable form for archival

Tags: macos, messages

I have a long (several months' worth) iMessage conversation with a contact.  He lost these messages when he re-installed his OS, but I still have the archive.  There is some important information there that we'd like to keep.

Is there a simple way to export this conversation for archival in a human readable form, and also keep any images?

I can select parts of the conversation, copy it to the clipboard and paste it into a rich text document, but this discards all images.  I'm looking for a way that keeps the images.

Note: I use iMessage on OS X only, not iOS.

(Ideally I'd also like to export all non-image file attachments, but I'm not expecting that this will be possible.)

Comment: Do you want to save them from an iDevice or a Mac ?

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler A Mac.  I don't use iMessage on iOS, so I didn't think of that possibility.  I'll update the question.

Comment: Does http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/88023/how-to-transfer-entire-imessage-conversations-to-computer help or are you looking for something else?

Comment: @patrix I am looking for a way to get the messages out of iMessage, so I can view them even if I stop using OS X.  I realize that it was a mistake to reply on iMessage to keep important information, so I want to move away from it completely, and hopefully salvage the chatlog for the future.

Answer (score 25):

If you know the iMessage account of your contact here is [a bash script of mine](https://github.com/kyro38/MiscStuff/blob/master/OSXStuff/iMessageBackup.sh) to retrieve text + images.

```
#Parameter is a iMessage account (email or phone number i.e. +33616.... )
if [ $# -lt 1 ]; then
    echo "Enter a iMessage account (email of phone number i.e +33616.....) "
fi
login=$1

#Retrieve the text messages 

sqlite3 ~/Library/Messages/chat.db "
select is_from_me,text from message where handle_id=(
select handle_id from chat_handle_join where chat_id=(
select ROWID from chat where guid='iMessage;-;$1')
)" | sed 's/1\|/me: /g;s/0\|/budy: /g' > MessageBackup.txt


#Retrieve the attached stored in the local cache

sqlite3 ~/Library/Messages/chat.db "
select filename from attachment where rowid in (
select attachment_id from message_attachment_join where message_id in (
select rowid from message where cache_has_attachments=1 and handle_id=(
select handle_id from chat_handle_join where chat_id=(
select ROWID from chat where guid='iMessage;-;$1')
)))" | cut -c 2- | awk -v home=$HOME '{print home $0}' | tr '\n' '\0' | xargs -0 -t -I fname cp fname .
```

Comment: Thanks, this is useful.  This won't give me the images though ...

Comment: I'll dig a bit more to find them ;)

Comment: Thanks!  I just found a solution which is good enough for now, so please don't spend your time on this any more.

Comment: hi, how to run this script

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25202168/converting-ichat-file-into-text-formate-using-applescript-or-any-other-script

Comment: How could I add the date in front of the message text?  I am aware of how to include the date in the SQL query, but not the sed bit.

Answer (score 13):

I took the liberty of furthering the above answer by Matthieu. I wrote a script that would automate the process by backing up all the user's messages, including images, audio files, and movies--storing each conversation into a text file by phone number.

https://github.com/PeterKaminski09/baskup

Edit: I developed the script into an OS X app with some nice features like contact recognition. https://peterkaminski09.github.io/baskup

Comment: What if the contact has no phone number?

Comment: I retrieve all contact info from the chat table in ./Library/Messages/chat.db. This is not specific on user phone numbers. Just their id that is associated with their messages. In most instances this is in fact a phone number.

Comment: I used it. It worked. It was the only solution I found that didn't cost money. Thank you!

Comment: I used it. It worked. Very nicely I should add. +1 'cos that's all I can give for a single answer.

Comment: I used the script and it still works in Mac OS 15 Catalina. Thanks

Answer (score 11):

I found a workable solution:

1. Scroll up until all messages are loaded
2. Print to PDF
3. (If you have Acrobat,) crop off the margins from the pages to improve readability of split-across-pages messages.

The result doesn't look *great*, but it does contain all the images and the text is searchable.  So it's good enough.

Comment: What if you have 25,000 messages in the conversation and scrolling up is not viable?

Comment: It takes a little time, but I think this solution is good for many use cases.

Answer (score 6):

### Archiving

This person appears to have a more polished solution (no disrespect intended to the extremely useful SQLite scraper above):

http://www.chrisfinke.com/2013/11/05/convert-ichat-transcripts-to-useable-xml/

To summarise the blog:

- install [Adium](https://adium.im/)
- choose the "import from iChat" option
- Adium transcripts are generated from your logs and stored in:

  ~/Library/Application Support/Adium 2.0/Users/Default/Logs/

The converted files are in HTML, more easily readable and hopefully more archive-friendly, but the `sqlite` approach to attachment linkage looks sensible.

### Attachments

Note that iMessage attachments tend to live in:

```
~/Library/Containers/com.apple.iChat/Data/Library/Messages/Attachments/...
```

(I don't know the rules for what goes in there and what doesn't, so it might not be complete - but there's a fair amount in there)

But actually you *can* see some information about the contact and conversation in the 
file's extended attributes:

```
$ xattr -lp com.apple.metadata:kMDItemWhereFroms <attachment>
```

will print an origin if Messages put one there on download.

Comment: Yes, @Szabolcs, I did see the "please don't spend your time on this any more" comment, but had to do a bit of digging of my own so thought I ought to share in case it's useful to someone else.

Answer (score 0):

Your mac should automatically save them. Here are instructions on how to extract them:

http://www.imore.com/how-view-and-move-your-imessage-history-and-attachments

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different!  Please don't give link-only answers.  We're looking for answers that provide explanations of why it answers the question.  Links can change over time and then we'll lose the question-answer context.  See [answer] for info on what makes up a good answer.  - From Review -

Answer (score -1):

[Export iMessages](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/export-messages-save-print/id952632588?mt=8) app allows you to save, print, backup and recover SMS/iMessages to your Mac/PC.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question as I explicitly said that I use iMessage *only* on OS X, not on iOS.